# Increase element padding as browser width decreases

Tags: html, css, width, padding

Default behavior for padding in CSS behaves as expected and will not increase when the browser width is decreased. In the snippet below a percent based value for padding will *decrease* as width *decreases* like expected.

[image]

```css
html {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #fe0;
  padding: 4%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Highlighted Text</h1>
```

I've learned some interesting CSS techniques using `calc` and `vw`, `vh`, etc. values to do some interesting non-standard behavior.

**Can I reverse default behavior and *increase padding* while *width decreases* ( Or at least create an illusion of this ) using CSS?**

**EDIT: Also I'm aware of media-queries but I want this transition to be buttery smooth like how default padding works.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you go :)

```css
html {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #fe0;
  padding: calc(50px - 4%);
}
```

```html
<h1>Highlighted Text</h1>
```

Comment: This is not the only possible solution, but I think it's the easiest and the smoothest.